# Watchdog on windows with python3.4

Tags: windows, python-3.4, python-watchdog

I am trying to learn to use watchdog utility on windows.

I have gone through basic examples available on google.
I am trying to write a script which will monitor a given directory and then will send mail if any sub-directory is created which has a file named version.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import DirCreatedEvent
import re
import smtplib




class MyHandler(DirCreatedEvent):

    def process(self,event):


        fileTocheck = "Version"

        with open(event.src_path+"\\"+fileTocheck) as version:
            chngstring = version.read()
            changeNumber = re.findall(r"\D(\d{5})\D",chngstring)
            if not changeNumber:
                return


        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        server.login("xyz@gmail.com","abc@123")
        message = "New Build has been create with Chnage Number %d"  %int(changeNumber[0])
        server.sendmail("xyz@gmail.com","abc@gmail.com",message)

    def on_created(self,event):
        self.process(event)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    observer = Observer()
    path = "D:\\"
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(),path,recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

The problem is that whenever I am running the script I am getting this error:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART   ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Prince/Desktop/KeepLearing/Watchdog.py", line 37, in <module>
observer.schedule(MyHandler(),path,path,recursive=True)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'src_path'
```

I am providing proper path while envoking observer.schedule, I don't understand why I am getting this.

Please help me find out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
class MyHandler(DirCreatedEvent):
```

You've made your handler a subclass of `DirCreatedEvent`.  The error is arising because `DirCreatedEvent`'s `__init__` method, which you are not overriding in your `MyHandler` class, [has one parameter, named `src_path`](http://pythonhosted.org/pydica-watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.DirCreatedEvent), and when you create a handler using  `MyHandler()`, you're not passing in any value for this parameter.

It would be more correct to say your handler *handles* events than to say your handler *is* an event.  So instead of subclassing `DirCreatedEvent`, you need to subclass an event handler, and [`FileSystemEventHandler`](http://pythonhosted.org/pydica-watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler) seems to be the one you want.

So, change the above line to

```
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
```

Also, import the `FileSystemEventHandler` class from `watchdog.events`.

Note that your `MyHandler` class will receive events for file creation as well as for directory creation.  The easiest way to ignore them is to modify your `on_created` method to:

```
    def on_created(self,event):
        if isinstance(event, DirCreatedEvent):
            self.process(event)
```

Comment: It helped Thanks, but I had to import that DirCreatedEvent separately for isinstance to work.